# convert a std::vector of objects from/to a std::vector of unsigned char

Tags: c++

i have some classes defined as below, only holds some simple datatypes

```
class A
{
public:
  float xxx;
  int yyy;
}
```

i want to covert a vector of that objects to a vector of unsigned char, and vice versa.
Is there a quick solution for doing that?

Thanks!

update!

thanks @Maciej Załucki, it's exactly what i need, a great help indeed!
 I refactored your code into the below methods,hope you dont mind.

```
template<typename T>
static vector<T> blob_to_vectorT(vector<unsigned char>& buffer) {
    vector<T> result(buffer.size() / sizeof(T));
    memcpy(result.data(), buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
static vector<unsigned char> vectorT_to_blob(vector<T>& dataT) {
    int datasize = sizeof(T) * dataT.size();
    vector<unsigned char> result(datasize);
    memcpy(result.data(), dataT.data(), datasize);
    return result;
}
```

and i also figured it out in my own way.

```
template<typename T>
static vector<T> blob_to_vectorT(vector<unsigned char>& buffer) {
    const T* bytesT = reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&buffer[0]);
    vector<T> result(bytesT, bytesT + buffer.size() / sizeof(T));
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
static vector<unsigned char> vectorT_to_blob(vector<T>& dataT) {
    const unsigned char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&dataT[0]);
    vector<unsigned char> result(bytes, bytes + sizeof(T) * dataT.size());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How would you *transform* this class to a single character (or multiple characters)? For some specific instance with specific values, what should the result be? Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)., and please try to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us.

Comment: This depends on how you intend to convert an `A` to an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @icewill Please clarify the question.

Answer (score -1):

Let me guess, this vector of unsigned char is actually some kind of serialized data?
Simplest way is just

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(sizeof(A));
memcpy(vec.data(), &a, sizeof(A));
```

You can do it in reverse to get your structure back. It does not care about paddings (will be copied as well). If you want one vector with many items, then simply create vector of size you want and move data by offset.

```
std::vector<A> source;
[...]
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(sizeof(A) * source.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < source.size(); ++i)
{
    memcpy(vec.data() + (sizeof(A) * i), &source[i], sizeof(A));
}
```

Or if you want to be lazy/smart (is that synonymous?), just do that:

```
std::vector<A> source;
[...]
size_t dataSize = sizeof(A) * source.size();
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(dataSize);
memcpy(vec.data(), source.data(), dataSize);
```

As an example (no sanity checks done).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class A
{
public:
    int i;
    float f;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> source;
    source.push_back({1, 2.345});
    source.push_back({6, 7.89});

    // Serialize

    size_t dataSize = sizeof(A) * source.size();
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec(dataSize);
    std::memcpy(vec.data(), source.data(), dataSize);

    for (unsigned char ch : vec)
    {
        std::cout << (unsigned)ch << " ";
    }

    // Deserialize
    std::vector<A> dest(vec.size() / sizeof(A));
    std::memcpy(dest.data(), vec.data(), vec.size());

    std::cout << "\n" << dest[0].i << " " << dest[0].f;
    std::cout << "\n" << dest[1].i << " " << dest[1].f;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7801aa3a17cd171f

Comment: I modified the post, dont know if you can see it ,so i replied here, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @icewill You have to remember that it is not secured in any way. Data structures can be stored differently on different architectures or even between compilers, then it will not deserialize it properly on the other side. You are safe if you use that internally or even send over some sockets/files to other executable built the same way.
Besides that you can at least check `(buffer.size() % sizeof(T)) == 0`.

Comment: Of course it works only for const size data (built in types and POD). For more complex mechanisms it's much better to actually implement serializers.